# Minimum Cut in undirected graphs

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I would like to quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_k-cut)

> In mathematics, the minimum k-cut, is a combinatorial optimization
>   problem that requires finding a set of edges whose removal would
>   partition the graph to k connected components.

It is said to be the minimum cut if the set of edges is minimal.

For a k = 2, It would mean Finding the set of edges whose removal would **Disconnect** the graph into 2 **connected** components.

However, The same article of Wikipedia says that:

> For a fixed k, the problem is polynomial time solvable in O(|V|^(k^2))

My question is Does this mean that minimum 2-cut is a problem that belongs to complexity class P?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The min-cut problem is solvable in polynomial time and thus yes it is true that it belongs to complexity class P. Another article related to this particular problem is the [Max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the time complexity an algorithm should be evaluated by expressing the number of steps the algorithm requires to finish as a function of the **length of the input** (see [Time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)). More or less formally, if you vary the length of the input, how would the number of steps required by the algorithm to finish vary?

Second of all, the time complexity of an algorithm is not exactly the same thing as to what complexity class does the problem the algorithm solves belong to. For one problem there can be multiple algorithms to solve it. The primality test problem (i.e. testing if a number is a prime or not) is in **P**, but some (most) of the algorithms used in practice are actually not polynomial.

Third of all, in the case of most algorithms you'll find on the Internet evaluating the time complexity is not done by definition (i.e. not as a function of the length of the input, at least not expressed directly as such). Lets take the good old naive primality test algorithm (the one in which you take `n` as input and you check for division by `2,3...n-1`). How many steps does this algo take? One way to put it is `O(n)` steps. This is correct. So is this algorithm polynomial? Well, it is linear in `n`, so it is polynomial in `n`. But, if you take a look at what time complexity means, the algorithm is actually exponential. First, what is the length of the input to your problem? Well, if you provide the input `n` as an array of bits (the usual in practice) then the length of the input is, roughly said, `L = log n`. Your algorithm thus takes `O(n)=O(2^log n)=O(2^L)` steps, so exponential in `L`. So the naive primality test is in the same time linear in `n`, but exponential in the length of the input `L`. Both correct. Btw, the AKS primality test algorithm is polynomial in the size of input (thus, the primality test problem is in **P**).

Fourth of all, what is **P** in the first place? Well, it is a class of problems that contains all **decision problems** that can be solved in polynomial time. What is a decision problem? A problem that can be answered with yes or no. Check these two Wikipedia pages for more details: [P (complexity)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_(complexity)) and [decision problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem).

Coming back to your question, the answer is no (but pretty close to yes :p). The minimum 2-cut problem is in **P** if formulated as a decision problem (your formulation requires an answer that is not just a yes-or-no). In the same time the algorithm that solves the problem in `O(|V|^4)` steps is a polynomial algorithm in the size of the input. Why? Well, the input to the problem is the graph (i.e. vertices, edges and weights), to keep it simple lets assume we use an adjacency/weights matrix (i.e. the length of the input is at least quadratic in `|V|`). So solving the problem in `O(|V|^4)` steps means polynomial in the size of the input. The algorithm that accomplishes this is a proof that the minimum 2-cut problem (if formulated as decision problem) is in **P**.

A class related to **P** is **[FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FP_(complexity))** and your problem (as you formulated it) belongs to this class.